# How to create alerts in Grafana (Based on Loki Logs)

Tags: alert, grafana

I created some Dashboards in Grafana to monitor the logs of the Kubernetes Pods. Below is a screenshot taken from a part of the Dashboard. So it basically shows "Fail" logs in red color as below. But I need something alerting to be done whenever if a "Fail" log occured.

[image]

[image]

It doesn't show me to add "Alerts" under this Dashboard. I need a solution that Alerts Fail logs. Can someone tell me how can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 9):

Here's an [explainer video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdgX46KwKqo) - while in that video they use Loki as `prometheus` type data source, it works just as well when using `loki` type.

#### TL;DW

1. Open the alerting section in Grafana and create an alert
2. Define a rule - note that **you need to use a metric query** (see [docs](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/metric_queries/)), e.g.:

```
count_over_time(
  {app="bot"}[15m]
    |= "ERROR"  
)
```

This rule will return a graph of the count of log lines containing ERROR within 15 minutes

If you need the total count, wrap it with `sum(...)`